# How do I disable these GNOME shell extension prompts on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I've ran into this weird problem.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed some shell themes to try them out after installing 'User Themes' extension. One of them being some MacOS one and for that I installed 'Dash to Dock' extension too. Later I removed the theme and switched to 'Dash to Panel' and removed 'Dash to Dock' and 'User Themes'. Still a prompt keeps coming out of nowhere asking if I want to install them. Also I checked there are some settings in Dconf Editor related to Dash to Dock even after removing it. I'm not able to understand what did I do wrong.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of Dash to Dock prompt]
[image: Screenshot of User Themes prompt]

They're both normal install prompts but I've noticed that the prompt appears whenever I launch the Firefox.

How do I disable those prompts? It's really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your GNOME shell extensions list got synced and thus the browser is always trying to install the "*missing*" extensions once you launch it. After opening Firefox, do the following:

1. Open the '*Add-ons*' tab (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
2. Look for the '**GNOME Shell Integration**' extension in the *Extensions* section and open its preferences.
3. Select **No** for the '*Synchronize GNOME Shell extensions list*' option.